# How to add adminstrator permissions in android to prevent app deletion ?

Tags: android, admin

I looked at Device Administration class in Android developers page. But, there are no methods to prevent app deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But in order to delete app, you need to deactivate active admin. And your admin can receive this event(i.e. deactivation) and lock the phone with password. That's the only usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to prevent user to delete app, try using some of application for locking. Those application ask for code in order to access to forbidden app or to settings. Best way, in my opinion, to restrict use of device.